# Change ios app specific password

Tags: ios, apple-id

Hi I am finally submitting my first app to the app store.  I downloaded the program application launcher.  It had me go to appleid.apple.com and create a app specific password.  I would never remember this password lol.  I have been searching on google and places to see how to change this password but I can not find any options.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the generated password, but you can always generate a new one and use that one.

When you go to appleid.apple.com, and check your Security settings you should see `Generate Password`

[image]

You give it a name and click Generate, and then the password will show up and you can copy it and paste it to the program you need it to.